# How to use latex macros with pandoc?

Tags: pandoc

The pandoc [User's Guide](http://pandoc.org/README.html#latex-macros) states (emphasis added):

> For output formats other than LaTeX, pandoc will **parse LaTeX \newcommand and \renewcommand** definitions **and apply the resulting macros** to all LaTeX math. So, for example, the following will work in all output formats, not just LaTeX:

```
\newcommand{\tuple}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}

$\tuple{a, b, c}$
```

> In LaTeX output, the \newcommand definition will simply be passed unchanged to the output.

For example, using this test file:

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

The gravitational force 

$$\vec{g}$$

The gravitational force 

$$\mathbf{g}$$

And with some code:

~~~{.cpp .numberLines startFrom="1"}
class A {}; 
~~~
```

and converting it with `pandoc test.md -o test.html` results in

```
<p>[1]{}</p>
<p>The gravitational force</p>
<p><br /><span class="math display">$$\vec{g}$$</span><br /></p>
<p>The gravitational force</p>
<p><br /><span class="math display"><strong>g</strong></span><br /></p>
<p>And with some code:</p>
<div class="sourceCode" startFrom="1"><table class="sourceCode cpp numberLines"><tr class="sourceCode"><td class="lineNumbers"><pre>1
</pre></td><td class="sourceCode"><pre><code class="sourceCode cpp"><span class="kw">class</span> A {}; </code></pre></td></tr></table></div>
```

If pandoc really parses the `newcommand` and `renewcommand`, why is the latex source code left within the HTML file for the first **g** vector:

```
<p><br /><span class="math display">$$\vec{g}$$</span><br /></p>
```

while the other latex equation defining the **g** vector was successfully converted into the boldface **g** letter?

Is this an inconsistency? The result is the same when enabling the `latex_macros` extension by calling `pandoc test.md --from markdown+latex_macros -o test.html`.

Comment: should it not be `\renewcommand{\vec}` instead of `\renewcommand{vec}`

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a typo. This document:

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

The gravitational force 

$$\vec{g}$$

The gravitational force 

$$\mathbf{g}$$

And with some code:

~~~{.cpp .numberLines startFrom="1"}
class A {}; 
~~~
```

Gives the expected output with `pandoc test.md -o test.html` (line 2 and 4 are identical as expected: `\vec` has been defined as `\mathbf`)

```
<p>The gravitational force</p>
<p><br /><span class="math display"><strong>g</strong></span><br /></p>
<p>The gravitational force</p>
<p><br /><span class="math display"><strong>g</strong></span><br /></p>
<p>And with some code:</p>
<div class="sourceCode" startFrom="1"><table class="sourceCode cpp numberLines"><tr class="sourceCode"><td class="lineNumbers"><pre>1
</pre></td><td class="sourceCode"><pre><code class="sourceCode cpp"><span class="kw">class</span> A {}; </code></pre></td></tr></table></div>
```